# How to enable submit button in jQuery in the same function for fields and droplists?

Tags: jquery

When all the inputs get touched the submit button enables but I want this to happen with the 2 `droplists` as well. I am not sure how to add that to my function.
So in order for the submit button to enable everything must be touched the inputs and the dropdowns.

Here is my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jpokusa/40tghh9q/)

Comment: Removed empty lines

Answer (score 0):

Using what code you already had, i've updated your fiddle wot work with the selects too: https://jsfiddle.net/40tghh9q/2/

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   $('#firstname, #lastname, #subject-property, #city, #zip, #ddlState, #ddlBankOrBroker').on('change', function() {
      if(allFilled()) $('#register').removeAttr('disabled');
  });

  function allFilled() {
      var filled = true;
      $('#LosForm input, #LosForm select').each(function() {
          if($(this).val() == '')  filled = false;

      });
      return filled;
  }
});
```

Please do note that this could be written much better, but it's how you've written it and there may be reason for doing so, so i left it as is.

Comment: Thank you for your help that worked butI have 2 add a checkbox and radio button then i am finished. I can seem to do it.

Comment: I have updated the fiddle please check it out.


https://jsfiddle.net/jpokusa/40tghh9q/